# Use fetched txt file correctly - Java

Tags: java, android

I am fetching text from a single lined txt file on a server. The fetched works fine and gives me the correct string. The fetched string is "blight".
Althought the if condition in my mainActivity.java makes the status text view set to "The plant is healthy". It should set the textview to "The plant is sick".

I tried with the code below in order to check the value of str :

```
status.setText(str) // output : "blight"
```

My mainActivity.java :

```java
        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try  {
                    try {
                        // Create a URL for the desired page
                        URL url = new URL("******/cnn-plant-disease.txt");
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                        // Read all the text returned by the server
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                        String str = in.readLine();
                        if(str == "blight"){
                            status.setText("The plant is sick");
                            status.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        } else {
                            status.setText("The plant is healthy");
                            status.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        }

                        in.close();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                    } catch (IOException e) {


                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });

        thread.start();
```

cnn-plant-disease.txt file :

```
blight
```

How can I correctly check if str == "blight" ?

Comment: use equals instead of == for string comparison "blight".equals(str)

Answer (score 0):

Strings are treated as objects in Java, so all the string values are allocated in a special memory from heap call string pool.

When you compare two objects with == in Java, as it's in your case, you compare if they have the same address in heap, not their value, `equals` method instead test value equality.